# Relativity of time

Tags: special-relativity

I have considered the special relativity and time dilation equations. I found that time dilation in clock moving with velocity (v) observed from rest is $T'=T(\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}) $and time dilation in clock at rest observed from moving body is $T'=T/(\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2})$. Are these equation holds good in their respective frame of reference? If yes, why time does not increases for one and decreases for other with the same rate. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the perspective of each observer the other one is in motion with the relative velocity $v$ between them. Moreover, the Lorentz factor depends on the square of the magnitude of the velocity and not on the sign of the velocity.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you've discovered one form of the twin paradox. The answer is that both observers observe the other person's clock to be running slower. Strange but true.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to give an intuitive explanation.

The way each person reads the other's clock is to send out a radar pulse, which reflects back and contains the other person's clock reading.
Then, each one considers the other's clock to have had that reading *half way between* sending and receiving the radar pulses.

I think it helps to visualize a space-time diagram, like this:

[image]

The units of time are years, and the units of X are light-years, so the 45-degree line represents the speed of light.

There are two people, A and B, and just for simplicity, they start at 0,0 and travel in opposite directions at high speed (but less than the speed of light).
Each one sends out radar pulses (shown in light gray) to read the other's clock.

You can see that at time 1.2, A reads B's clock as 1. Similarly at time 1.2, B reads A's clock as 1.
(What each considers to be "the same time" is shown in blue.)
So each thinks the other's clock is running slow.

Comment: Mike. If both the clocks run slower then, why the answer I get from the equations I have written in question above differently . the equation in which rest time is dividing with Lorentz factor always has the answer more than the rest time and the time dilation calculated from other equation results in the answer less than the rest time. Why?

Comment: @PiyushKapoor: Either clock can be considered as "at rest" with the other "moving". That's why it's called "relativity". So I think your second statement $T'=T/(\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2})$ is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

> and time dilation in clock at rest observed from moving body is
>   $T′=T/\sqrt{1−v^2/c^2}$.

It isn't quite clear to me what you're thinking about here when you write *"a clock at rest as observed from a moving body"*.

Let's say that Alice observes that Bob is moving uniformly.  What we mean is that, in an inertial coordinate system in which Alice's position is constant with time, Bob's position is changing uniformly with time.

So, in Alice's coordinates, Bob is moving.

But motion is *relative*.

In an inertial coordinate system in which Bob's position is constant with time, Alice's position is changing uniformly with time and thus, in Bob's coordinates, Alice is moving.

Clearly, a clock at rest in Alice's coordinates is moving in Bob's coordinates.  To observe the rate at which Alice's clock runs, Bob must use *two* spatially separated clocks, both at rest and synchronized in Bob's coordinates.

It's easy to show, via the Lorentz transformations that relate Alice's and Bob's coordinates, that Bob finds Alice's clock runs slower than clocks at rest in Bob's coordinates.

However, exchanging the names Alice and Bob in the above two paragraphs does not change the result.

That is, Bob (Alice) finds that Alice's (Bob's) clock runs slowly compared to clocks at rest in Bob's (Alice's) coordinates.

In summary, I don't know what to make of *"a clock at rest as observed from a moving body"*.

A clock at rest with respect to Alice (Bob) as observed by a moving Bob (Alice) is *not* at rest according to Bob (Alice).

Put another way:  "a clock at rest *[at rest according to whom?]* as observed from a moving body *[moving according to whom?]*".

Answer (score -2):

The equation is useful for calculating the value of the discrepancy but it doesn't tell you the sign (which frame is the one the experienced more/less time). To find that out you'd need to know which inertial frame is the one that changed in reference to the other (accel/deceleration is not relative).

Comment: No assumption was made about acceleration or deceleration, so this answer is at least irrelevant and at worst very badly misleading.

Comment: The last line of his question seemed to be asking this but i could be wrong.

Comment: The sign is symmetric. Each participant sees time running slowly for the other. And they are both right, because they are not comparing the same pair of space-time events.

Comment: They see time running slower for each other but unless their acceleration is uniform there will be differences in the amount of progression each frame undergoes. Again, i was just going by what it seemed like the OP was asking.

Answer (score -3):

Suppose we have a clock in a moving spaceship which is cruising at 99.995% of the speed of light (299,777,468.3771 metres/sec) on a journey of 200 light-years;

using the following equation:

$$
γ = {1\over \sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}
$$

$γ = 100.$

This means that an observer with a clock at rest will find that the moving clock is moving slower by the $γ$ (gamma) factor which is 100.

So for example, if several successive generation of observers at rest on Earth will observe the spacecraft for the duration of its journey, they will find that the spacecraft's clock is moving really slowly to the point that though 200 years will have passed on earth yet the spacecraft's clock will record only 2 years.

However the spacecraft's occupants will find that the clocks on earth are moving very fast in comparison to their own on-board clocks by the same gamma factor.

Your equations should be as follows:

- time dilation in clock moving with velocity (v) observed from rest is

$$
T' = t \sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}
$$

and

- time in clock at rest observed from moving body is

$$
t = {T'\over \sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}
$$

Time is being dilated only for the moving observer, however the time in the rest frame is running normally.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this answer is 100% wrong.

Comment: "However the spacecraft's occupants will find that the clocks on earth are moving very fast in comparison to their own on-board clocks by the same gamma factor."  - just not true.

Comment: This answer is correct - that's what is meant by "relative"! In particle accelerators all over the world - this same phenomenon is observed with regard to particles being accelerated! This is also evidenced in GPS clocks.

Comment: If SR is understood completely, and thus the relativity of time is understood completely, then one knows exactly what one would see happening if one were able to view all possible frames of reference at the very same time. However, if exploration is confined to just comparing one frame of reference to another, then the actual ongoings will not have been fully exposed. In turn, from this limited point of view, "relativity" would remain confusing, and statements such as "strange but true" would continue to carry on concerning relativity.

Comment: Your answer depends on a absolute frame of reference so you can say the spaceship is moving and the Earth is at rest and therefore the clock on the spaceship run slower and the clock on the Earth run s faster.  But who is to say its not the Earth that's moving and the spaceship that is stationary.  Alfred Centuari explains it well in his answer.

Comment: We are using Earth as " stationary" frame of reference; however it is obiting the Sun at 29.78 km/sec which gives a gamma factor of 1.000000004933 and hence 200 years divide by this factor =199.999999 and therefore my answer remains intact. Nearly 200 years passed on Earth while on the spaceship only 2 years. Therefore the clock on the ship is moving slowly in "relation" to the clock on Earth and we can also say that the clock on Earth is running very quickly in "relation" to the clock on the ship!

Comment: However, if the two observers were both in a moving frame of reference, it is then, that they will find that their clocks are both running "slow" as compared to each other. However, the example I gave in my answer is a different case, where one observer is in a moving frame of reference and the other is in a near stationary one.